# JAVA calling a method using a ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary

I am trying to use ? to decide which method i want to call, but i do not need to assign a variable. My question: Is there a way to use the ternary operator with out assigning a variable?

```
(something i dont need) = (x == 1)? doThisMethod():doThatMethod()
```

instead of

```
if(x == 1) {
    doThisMethod()
} else {
    doThatMethod()
}
```

Comment: Have you simply tried it with `void` methods and no assignment target?  (I never have, but it's not clear that it wouldn't work.)

Comment: sorry my answer was wrong: you _can't_ use the ternary operator as a lone statement in java; you _can_ in C.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will not work, as it is not the intended use of the ternary operator.

If you really want it to be 1 line, you can write:

```
if (x==1) doThisMethod(); else doThatMethod();
```

Comment: This worked. and thank you for the knowledge. I do want to keep it easy for other people to follow.

Comment: -1: completely wrong. This has nothing to do with the return-type of the method. Changing the methods to return (say) `int` or `Object` would not fix the syntax error.

Comment: @ruakh, the question that i asked is basically can i make the ternary operator basically a void so that i wouldnt have to assign a variable. for the question that i aske this is the best answer. (because, i actually didnt need the ternary operator, just an "else". so if anybody gets the -1 its me.

Comment: @ruakh it works fine if the methods have a return type (As I stated in the answer), I just tried it.

Comment: @KDiTraglia: No, you misunderstood the question. The question asked, "Is there a way to use the ternary operator with out assigning a variable?". In essence, your answer says: "Yes, it's possible to use the ternary operator without assigning a variable. All you have to do is -- assign a variable."

Comment: and i did actually end up returning something and this did compile.

Comment: I've now edited the answer to remove all the wrong claims, and will therefore retract my down-vote.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that this works. The [JLS §15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) defines the ternary expression as follows:

```
ConditionalExpression:
    ConditionalOrExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
```

And a `ConditionalExpression` isn't a [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) by itself. It can be used in various other places, though, e.g. an [`Assignment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

```
AssignmentExpression:
    ConditionalExpression
    Assignment

Assignment:
    LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [§14.8 "Expression Statements" of the *Java Language Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8), the only expressions that can be used alone as statements are:

- assignments
- pre– and post-increments and pre– and post-decrements
- method calls
- class instance creation expressions (constructor calls)

Answer (score -5):

Much more diversified, if the flow was to break after the method call.this can be used, but a word of caution if the flow does not break after the if then both methods will get executed.

```
if (x==1) 
doThisMethod();
doThatMethod();
```

Comment: This will calll `doThatMethod();` all the time, no matter what x is.

Comment: @hinneLinks made it little bit more verbose, sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you mean `return doThisMethod();` then you should write it. If you mean, that you rely on `doThisMethod()` to throw an Exception in order to prevent the call of `doThatMethod();` this would be very bad code style, nobody would expect that.